# How to get the number of values for a Date attribute

Tags: java, weka

I want to iterate over something using the amount of values for a Date Attribute. However, when i use numValues function of the attribute i get 0, eventhough there are 144 instances with unique dates.

I am using airline.arff, a demo arff file that is included in the weka application.

```
int numberOfValues = this.data.classAttribute().numValues()
for (int classLabelIndex = 0; classLabelIndex < numberOfValues; classLabelIndex++) {
            String classLabel = this.data.classAttribute().value(classLabelIndex);
            AttributeMap attributes = setAttributes();
            this.groups.put(classLabel, attributes);
        }
```

I am aware that with this dataset i could just use the number of instances but i would like to be able to use this for other arff files aswell, where there might be more instances with the same date.

Answer (score 0):

**Date** attributes are considered numeric attributes. `numValues` will return 0 for non-nominal attributes. Instead, you need to iterate through the data rows itself and collect the values, e.g., in a `HashSet`:

```java
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class IterateDateValues {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Instances data = DataSource.read(args[0]);
    int index = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.numInstances(); i++)
      values.add(data.instance(i).stringValue(index));
    System.out.println(values);
    System.out.println(values.size());
  }
}
```